# My Android App doesn't automatically push updates

Tags: android, google-play, updates, self-updating

This is a publication issue!

I've made my app, and I've published it on the Google Play Store. Problem is, whenever I want to update the application, it works fine, but I've noticed on my clients' devices that the app doesn't automatically update. Instead they have to uninstall and reinstall the application in order to receive updates! This really isn't ideal, because my app frequently gets new features, and I would like my users to receive full functionality available without manually having to uninstall and reinstall the app! What should I do?

Thanks in advance, 
YomanAwe

Comment: Why can't they update? What does it say? Are you giving the update enough time to show on Google Play? It might take a few hours.

Comment: check versionCode in your android manifest. The update should contain a greater versionCode than the current version http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Comment: It really doesn't say anything... When I update I change the versionCode, and it seems like it works perfectly but the app doens't update on my mom's phone

Comment: In play store how is the updated version show to a user who has already installed ?

Comment: It doesn't show that there is an update.. almost as if they have the newest update. However they don't and when I uninstall and reinstall the app, they have the newest version.